# How to nest a div within another div from a for loop using slim

Tags: html, for-loop, nested, frontend, slim-lang

I have the following code

```
div class = "content"
- for x in list
  -if x == "test"
    div id = "two"
```

I would expect `div id = "two` to be nested within `div class="content` however it appears as its own separate div. How would I go about nesting the div within the content div based on the conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indent lines 2-4, otherwise they're treated as siblings. To quote [the docs](https://github.com/slim-template/slim)...

> Indentation matters, but the indentation depth can be chosen as you like. If you want to first indent 2 spaces, then 5 spaces, it's your choice. **To nest markup you only need to indent by one space**, the rest is gravy.

```
div class = "content"
  - for x in list
    -if x == "test"
      div id = "two"
```